# Work out an approximate lat/lng translation by a mileage distance

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to find the lat/lng coordinate that lies 10 miles north, south, east and west of an origin coordinate, I have an approximate rule that states:

```
Latitude: 1 deg = 110.54 km
Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km
```

How might I write formulas such that I can pass them an origin coordinate and a mileage and have each return to me the coordinate that lies 10 miles either north, south, east and west of the origin coordinate?

Thanks

Comment: What if you're 5 miles from a pole?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the nonspherical nature of Earth, one (nautical) mile is always one minute in latitude. For the longitude, the mile gets "longer" (when expressed in minutes) by a factor of $\frac 1{\cos \alpha}$ if $\alpha$ is the latitude.

Comment: The miles in the question are almost certainly not nautical ones, but the 1609-meter miles that Americans use to measure (land) distances.